# Entity Framework Core version 5 problem with unique constraint

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have problem with unique constraint in EF Core 5 (5.0.11).

I created a method `OnModelCreating` in `UserContext`:

```
    public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options) :base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasIndex(b => b.Email)
            .IsUnique();
    }
```

And or in the model

```
[Index(nameof(Email), IsUnique = true)]
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

But if I run migration I have got only this (without unique constraint)

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "users",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_users", x => x.Id);
            });
    }
```

Comment: You don't need both configurations. Did you rebuild the project?

Comment: @GertArnold yes the problem was solved by rebuild the project. Thank you